# document.getElementById('form_name').submit() not working properly

Tags: php, javascript, html

Ok, I will try to give the most details I can.

The site is not suposed to work with IE6. It would be nice if it worked with IE8 and Chrome, but that can be done later.

The site is in PHP. The form where the submit is in another PHP file that is included in position on the index.php inside of a DIV tag.

If I open the form solely, the submit works correcly, but when I try to submit on the index page, the Firefox error console says that document is undefined. The form code is echoed line by line via PHP. Save the text fields for username and password, the form code is the following:

```
<form id="entrar" action="entrar.php" method="post" onsubmit="javascript:checkvalues();">
  <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('entrar').submit();">ENTRAR</a>
</form>
```

What's the big deal? What am I missing here? I know it is something very silly but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Check the source of your page and make sure there is no another element with the same ID.

Comment: Ewww! Don't use links to submit forms! That will only piss off the people who are used to simply hitting the Enter key to submit them! USE A SUBMIT BUTTON!

Comment: Its considered poor practice to place javascript in the href of an anchor these days. It is also nice to separate the markup from the logic. If you are having problems getting script to work across all browsers then jQuery will be very useful for you.

Answer (score 3):

**In before jQuery answers.**

```
<form id="entrar" action="entrar.php" method="post" onsubmit="javascript:checkvalues();">
  <a id="entrar-link" href="#">ENTRAR</a>
</form>

<script>
(function() {
var entrar = document.getElementById('entrar'),
link = document.getElementById('entrar-link');

link.onclick=function() {  entrar.submit() }

})();
</script>
```

Bottom line is dont use `href` to execute javascript. Do it unobtrusively ( within a script element ). Make sure the `script` comes after the markup or if you do plan to put it in the head make the function invoke on window load / dom ready.

Though I honestly don't know why you just did:

```
<input type=submit value=go>
```

Unless you're doing this for some bizarre stylistic purpose, which you can also probably use `input type=image` for if you aren't sure how to properly style submits.

Comment: I can't use an input button. Unfortunately for me, I am not responsible for the layout of the webpage, and the client wants a text link. I am about to drop the javascript idea and go CSS route restyling the submit button as a text.

Comment: It shouldn't be about what the webmaster wants, it should be about what is most convenient for the users. You know, those people who will actually bring in profit.